# How do I truncate and completely rewrite a file without having leading zeros?

Tags: go

When truncating a file it seems to be adding additional zero bytes to the start:

```
configFile, err := os.OpenFile("./version.json", os.O_RDWR, 0666)
defer configFile.Close()
check(err)
//some actions happen here
configFile.Truncate(0)
configFile.Write(js)
configFile.Sync()
```

As a result the file has the contents I write with a section of `0` bytes at the beginning.

How do I truncate and completely rewrite a file without having leading zeros?

Comment: What are "some actions"? Are you seeking back to `(0, 0)` before calling `Truncate`? (unrelated, you can't defer before checking the error, or you'll panic if there is an error. Also, something that looks like `checkError(error)` is usually not a good pattern in Go).

Comment: No I wasn't. Thanks for the hints, very useful for the newcomer to go :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

See the [documentation on `Truncate`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Truncate):

> Truncate changes the size of the file. **It does not change the I/O offset**. If there is an error, it will be of type *PathError.

So you also need to seek to the beginning of the file before you write:

```
configFile.Truncate(0)
configFile.Seek(0,0)
```

As shorthand, use the flag `os.O_TRUNC` when calling `os.OpenFile` to truncate on open.

Comment: Good point,  will check this out.  Considered the Truncate function to work similarly to what php does. Guess this is the problem 

Comment: Yeah, this was it! Thanx for the hint.

Comment: On linux, `(File).Truncate` is backed by `syscall.Ftruncate` which requires file to be open for write https://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate. What follows, you will get error by calling it on file opened for read only. As an alternative, you can use `unix.Truncate(path string, length int64)` which only requires file to be writable (it don't have to be open).

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to show an alternative for cases where you may just want to truncate the file, then another option may be the following:

```
func truncate(filename string, perm os.FileMode) error {
    f, err := os.OpenFile(filename, os.O_TRUNC, perm)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not open file %q for truncation: %v", filename, err)
    }
    if err = f.Close(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("could not close file handler for %q after truncation: %v", filename, err)
    }
    return nil
}
```