# How to overwrite file content in golang

Tags: go

I have a empty file called `a.txt`, I want to output a value(int) to it in a loop, and overwrite last content in file `a.txt`. For example,

```
    // open a file
    f, err := os.Open("test.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    // another file
    af, err := os.OpenFile("a.txt", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer af.Close()

    b := []byte{}

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        b = append(b, scanner.Bytes()...)
        // how to output len(b) into a.txt?
    }
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use the [truncate](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Truncate) method and write again to file starting at the begining.

```
err = f.Truncate(0)
_, err = f.Seek(0, 0)
_, err = fmt.Fprintf(f, "%d", len(b))
```

Comment: This is only a partial solution as it will result in leading zeros at the beginning of the file. You also need to seek to the beginning.

```err = f.Truncate(0)
_, err = f.Seek(0, 0)```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44416790/1127720

Answer (score 50):

You can also try:

[os.OpenFile](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#OpenFile) with custom flags to truncate file, as shown below

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.OpenFile("notes.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use os.Create too as internally it uses the same code snippet

Answer (score 14):

Use `os.Create()` instead:

```
f, err := os.Create("test.txt")
```

From the func's doc:

> Create creates or truncates the named file. If the file already exists, it is truncated. If the file does not exist, it is created ...